# NHibernate: Enum to list and store values in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

I am using `enum`'s and a custom `Selector` class to help choose between radiobuttons, dropdowns, checkboxes, etc. I am using NHibernate. With a single selection (radiobuttons, dropdowns), the value from attribute `[Display(Name = "[Some Text]")]` will be populated in the database table (NOTE: I am using an extension to use `Display(Name)`). However, with multiple selections (checkboxes, multilist), I cannot figure out how to get the values of the `enum` selections into the database.

Here are parts of my model (each in separate files) (EDIT: I gave them generic names so as not to further confuse the issue):

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Display(Name = "Text for enum1")]
    enum1,
    //Left out 2 - 10 for brevity
    [Display(Name = "Text for enum10")]
    enum10
}
...
public class MyEnumSelectorAttribute : SelectorAttribute
{
    public override IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetItems()
    {
        return Selector.GetItemsFromEnum<MyEnum>();
    }
}
...
[Display(Name = "This is a checkboxlist (select one or more check boxes)?")]
[MyEnumSelector(BulkSelectionThreshold = 10)]
public virtual List<string> MyEnumCheckBox { get; set; }
...
public List<string> MyEnumCheckBox
{
    get { return Record.MyEnumCheckBox; }
    set { Record.MyEnumCheckBox = value; }
}
```

And here is the `Selector.cs` class (in case it's relevant to the problem) that help's to choose radiobuttons, checkboxes, dropdowns, etc.:

```
public class Selector
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }

    public string OptionLabel { get; set; }

    public bool AllowMultipleSelection { get; set; }

    public int BulkSelectionThreshold { get; set; }

    public static string GetEnumDescription(string value, Type enumType)
    {
        var fi = enumType.GetField(value.ToString());
        var display = fi
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false)
            .OfType<DisplayAttribute>()
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (display != null)
        {
            return display.Name;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetItemsFromEnum<T>
        (T selectedValue = default(T)) where T : struct
    {
        return from name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(T))
               let enumValue = Convert.ToString((T)Enum.Parse
                   (typeof(T), name, true))

               select new SelectListItem
               {
                   Text = GetEnumDescription(name, typeof(T)),
                   Value = enumValue,
                   Selected = enumValue.Equals(selectedValue)
               };
    }
}

public static class SelectorHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectList
        (this IEnumerable data)
    {
        return new SelectList(data);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectList
        (this IEnumerable data, string dataValueField, 
        string dataTextField)
    {
        return new SelectList(data, dataValueField, dataTextField);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>
        (this IEnumerable<T> data, Expression<Func<T, object>> 
        dataValueFieldSelector, Expression<Func<T, string>> 
        dataTextFieldSelector)
    {
        var dataValueField = dataValueFieldSelector.ToPropertyInfo().Name;
        var dataTextField = dataTextFieldSelector.ToPropertyInfo().Name;
        return ToSelectList(data, dataValueField, dataTextField);
    }
}
```

The `Selector` class is paired with a template `Selector.cshtml` that has some logic to figure out which to pick (radiobutton, checkboxes, etc.).

I am getting various errors trying either `List<string>`, `List<MyEnum>`, `IList<string>`, `IList<MyEnum>`, `IEnumerable<MyEnum>` and `IEnumerable<MyEnum>`. This error only comes with checkboxes or multilists since they use `List<string>`. Dropdowns, for example, work fine with no errors. Here is a sample dropdown model (can reuse `enum` above) that works and will allow mapping to the DB through NHibernate:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select one option")]
[Display(Name = "This is a dropdown list (select one option)?")]
[MyEnumSelector(BulkSelectionThreshold = 0)] //0 selects dropdown
public virtual MyEnum? MyEnumDropDown { get; set; }

public MyEnum? MyEnumDropDown
    {
        get { return Record.MyEnumDropDown; }
        set { Record.MyEnumDropDown = value; }
    }
```

Here are some of the errors I am getting based on what I've tried:

**`List<string>` error:**

> NHibernate.Transaction.ITransactionFactory - DTC transaction prepre phase failed
>   NHibernate.PropertyAccessException: Invalid Cast (check your mapping for property type mismatches); setter of MyNameSpace.Models.MyRecord ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag`1[System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.

**`List<MyEnum>` error:**

> NHibernate.Transaction.ITransactionFactory - DTC transaction prepre phase failed
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyNameSpace.Models.MyEnum]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[System.String]'.

**`IList<string>` error:**

> NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Could not execute command: INSERT INTO MyEnumCheckBox (MyRecord_id, Value) VALUES (@p0, @p1)
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException (0x80004005): The specified table does not exist. [ MyEnumCheckBox ]

The other variations I tried were similar errors, except that if I used `<MyEnum>` it would show an error like this:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyNameSpace.Models.MyEnum]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[System.String]'.

Any thoughts on how to use `enum`'s in this scenario when trying to insert multiple selected `enum`s using NHibernate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since using lists is used for separate tables by default in Nhibernate, you'll have to use a mapping functions to map a single value from the database to a list of values in your model.

I've demonstrated how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870455/trying-to-save-checkbox-selections-based-on-enums-in-orchard-nhibernate/13875372#comment19131858_13875372) with a working sample, but I'll sum it up once more on your question.

There are 2 major mapping function types based on your problem. They both include that you:

1. move your `MyEnumSelector` attribute from the `Record` class to your model class,
2. change the type of your `Record`'s `MyEnumCheckBox` property and
3. change your model's `MyEnumCheckBox` property so that it maps to and from your `Record`'s `MyEnumCheckBox` property

So those mapping functions are:

1. `int` to `List<MyEnumSelector>` - this is the same technique I've shown in the linking post. It includes marking your `MyEnumSelector` enum with the `[Flags]` attribute and setting it's items to be of values of subsequent powers of 2. Your `Record`'s `MyEnumCheckBox` property should be of type `int`. The mapping part then involves mapping the bits of the `Record`'s `MyEnumCheckBox` property to and from the list of corresponding `MyEnumSelector` values
2. `string` to `List<MyEnumSelector>` - this involves setting your `Record`'s `MyEnumCheckBox` property to be of type `string`. The mapping part then involves mapping the delimited string of the `Record`'s `MyEnumCheckBox` property to and from the list of corresponding `MyEnumSelector` values. Delimiter could be comma or semicolon or some other character that you won't use as a name of your `MyEnumSelector` item values.

Major differences of these 2 approaches are:

1. Enum size - when using `int` as your database type your're limited to 32 bits of data. This means that you can't have more than 32 items in your enum. `String`s don't have this kind of limitation
2. Ease of searching the database for specific values - when using `int`, you'll have to deal with bit-wise database operators which are quite messy and not that easy to work with, while you could use simple `LIKE` operator when using `string` mapping
3. Size used in database - `int` uses always 4 bytes (32-bits) while `string` mapping uses that amount (32-bits) for only one character inside the string (if it's of type `char`, `varchar` or `text`, and double the size - 64-bits when using `nchar`, `nvarchar` or `ntext`) so it will use much more space for each row in the database
4. Speed of mapping - bit-wise mapping used in `int` mapping is quite fast while `string` mapping uses string manipulation functions which are much slower. This shouldn't be the problem though if you're dealing with a small amount of data. But if you're going to deal with a massive amount of data this could be a huge issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would make the checkbox values the int value for the enums.

A few suggestions:

- Use [System.DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx) enum in place of your own enum.
- An enum can be mapped as a custom type in NHibernate.
- Since days of the week are one word, there's no need for a Display attribute. The control values should be the int value for the enum (you can direct cast).
- Use partial views for the different control sets (dropdown, radio, etc.)

Comment: Good point about `System.DayOfWeek` and the use of the `Display` attribute. However, this was one example. I am reusing the `enum` and `Selector` paradigm for all inputs. I have many other checkboxes. I was hoping not to have to change things around just for the checkboxes. For example, I have one checkbox with Income Types (full, part, self employed, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

PersistentGenericBag is definitely not a List<string>, but it does implement IList<string>:

```
public class PersistentGenericBag<T> : PersistentBag, IList<T>
```

When you use IList<string> instead, are you sure you get the exact same error from the same spot in the code?

Comment: No I get a different error. I did at least six (6) variations and this was the original error. I think one of the errors I got was "could not insert collection . . . specified table does not exist"

Comment: Well, since a PersistentGenericBag<> clearly isn't a List<> you should forget about that error. Try with e.g. IList<> instead. The full error information for that case is more interesting.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry if I misunderstand: do you want me to post the error information in the case of using `IList<>`? Question is, do I use `IList<string>` or `IList<[Name of my enum here]>`?

Comment: The original exception claims that PersistentGenericBag'1[System.String] cannot be casted, so I would try with IList<string> and see if that yields anything interesting.